# How to remove an unhealthy node in Google Kubernetes Engine Autopilot?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

My Kubernetes cluster running on GKE autopilot has an unhealthy node. The node has a `Ready` status, but all the pods running on it have a `CreateContainerError` status and seems to be stuck polling container images.

Example:

> (Normal  Pulled  101s (x1326 over 4h49m)  kubelet  Container image "gke.gcr.io/cluster-proportional-autoscaler:v1.8.10-gke.3@sha256:274afbfd520aef0933f1fefabddbb33144700982965f9e3632caabb055e912c6" already present on machine).

Something went wrong in a kubernetes upgrade because my account ran out of quota (apparently 1TB of compute storage isn't enough for a small cluster). I got more quota but the autopilot cluster doesn't repair itself.

I did "cordon" the node to mark it unschedulable, and manually deleted my pods from it. New pods got scheduled on healthier nodes, so not too bad.

Now I want to clean-up. The old pods were stuck in `Terminating` state, but force deleting them made them disappear.

I cannot do the same on the `kube-system` and `gke-gmp-system` namespaces. I see the "managed" pods with a `CreateContainerError` status, and they are pulling container images in a loop. One is also stuck with a `Terminating` status.

I would like to remove this node, [and apparently you need to drain the node and ignore the errors in the `kube-system` namespace](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/autopilot-clusters). I drained the node but it's still there.

How could I remove the unhealthy node?